# R Shiny in Memory Application or noSQL

Tags: r, redis, shiny, in-memory-database, nosql

I am running a tiny web app using R's shiny framework. The tool doesn't do that much. It's just filtering data frames with given parameters from the UI.
The problem I have now is the following. If a user is accessing the app via http it takes a long time to start the App. Since the data, which I load in the `global.R`, is pretty big (~5GB). After an initial start, the App is running smooth, also when re-accessing within a given time (the app seems to be completely in memory, for some minutes).
Since I got enough memory available, and my data doesn't change by user interaction, I am asking myself if I could keep the complete App in memory. Is it possible to force this? My server is running centOS 6. Also the problem isn't the file system, hard disk, etc. - I created a ram disk to load the data from, but the performance increase is marginal. So the bottle neck seems to be R, when processing the data.

Now I got two ideas, which may overcome the problem.

- Just as I mentioned, is it possible to keep the complete app in memory?
- Don't save the Data as R objects, instead use a fast noSQL DB e.g. Redis wich is in memory

May one of you has some experience when loading bigger data. I would be thankful if could get a discussion going. If it is possible, I would like to avoid external software, like Redis, to keep everything as simple as possible.

With all the best,

Mario

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with noSQL databases, but here is how I am combining shiny with an Oracle database to speed up my apps:

User inputs are passed to an sql query which is sent to the extremly fast database, and only the output of this query is read into R. In many cases (especially if the sql involves a group by statement) this reduces the number of observations to be read from several millions to a few hundreds. Hence, data loading becomes very fast.

In the example below users first select questionnaires and the date range. This generate an sql statement which filters the relevant observations and counts frequencies of answers per question and questionnaire. These frequencies are read into R and displayed as a datatable in the shiny app.

```
library(shiny)
library(ROracle)
library(DT)

drv <- dbDriver("Oracle")
con <-dbConnect(drv, username = "...", password = '...', dbname = "...")

query <- 'select distinct questionnaire from ... order by questionnaire'
questionnaire.list <- dbGetQuery(con, query)$questionnaire


ui <- fluidPage(
      selectInput('questionnaire_inp','Questionnaire',
                  choices=questionnaire.list,selected=questionnaire.list,multiple=T),
      dateRangeInput("daterange_inp", "Date range", 
                     start='2016-01-01', end=Sys.Date()),
      dataTableOutput('tbl')
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$tbl <- renderDataTable({
    query <- paste0(
        "select questionnaire, question, answer, count(*) from ... 
        where title in (", paste0(shQuote(input$questionnaire_inp), collapse=","), ")
        and date between to_date('", input$daterange_inp[1] ,"','YYYY-MM-DD') 
        and to_date ('", input$daterange_inp[1] ,"','YYYY-MM-DD') 
        group by questionnaire, question, answer")
    dt <- dbGetQuery(con, query)
    datatable(dt)

  })

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [set the timeout to be a longer value](http://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/#application-timeouts). I'm not sure if infinite value(or long enough value) is possible.

Other ways not involving a database may be:

1. use `data.table` `fread` if you read from csv. This can be several times faster than `read.csv`. Specify the column classes can further improve speed.
2. Or use binary format `.RDS` which should be fast and smaller in size thus quicker to read.

If you are using `.RDS` `.Rdata` already there is not much to do in this aspect.